# I cannot open folders in .tar file

Tags: windows-7, compression, tar

I've downloaded factory image for my Nexus4 mobile, the Image folder is compressed in .tar file but it tells me that its  unknown file Type: File ,, how can i open it? 
here take some photo of my problem 
And I'm using windows 7 32-bit
And I've downloaded the file from developer.google.com

Before Extracting

[image]

After extracting

[image]

Comment: Download and install 7 zip, right click on the extracted file and click on open with 7 zip

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [**7-Zip**](http://www.7-zip.org/), right click on the extracted file and click on "Open with 7-Zip".

Answer (score 0):

It's no ordinary image file. Assuming that you want to flash your device, the steps in brief are:

1. **Backup** if necessary.
2. Download and install **Android SDK Tools**. (Use the installer_*-windows.exe executable)
3. After the installation is completed, run **Android SDK Manager**.
4. Check and install both **'Android SDK Platform-tools'** and **'Google USB Drivers'**. No other boxes need to be checked.
5. Plug the device into your computer.
6. Open command prompt and [`cd`](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/232/right-click-to-open-a-command-prompt/) into 'Android-SDK-Manager\platform-tools' directory.
7. In terminal window (cmd), run the command `fastboot devices` to Confirm that the device is indeed being detected.
8. [Boot the device into Fastboot/Bootloader Mode](http://www.droidviews.com/how-to-boot-android-devices-in-fastboot-download-bootloader-or-recovery-mode/).
9. Extract the downloaded factory image file (7-zip recommended). Browse to that folder  and then copy and paste all the files into 'platform-tools' directory.
10. Run the file `flash-all.bat` to start the flashing process.